# How to use the ComboBox.Text as the Column in the WHERE statement of the query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-design, combobox, where-in

How do i use the ComboBox.Text as the Column in the WHERE statement of the query?

Here's my code.

```
  If cboShowOnly.Text = "Province" Then
            valCbo = "Prov_Name"
        ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Municipality" Then
            valCbo = "Mun_Name"
        ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Bank" Then
            valCbo = "BANK_ACCNT"
        ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Branch" Then
            valCbo = "Branch_Name"
        ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Assigned Account" Then
            valCbo = "Assigned_Account"
        End If

    Select * from view_remit WHERE '" & valCbo  & "' = '" & txtGroupBy.Text & "'"
```

the `Items`  listed in the `cboShowOnly.text` are the `column` names of the `view_remit`

here's the 
[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHuOy.png)

here's what i want to happen > 
[Image of working mysql statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpRdM.png)

am i doing it wrong? is there any other way?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the column name.

Comment: add a second combobox in your form, say, cboColumnName, you will populate this field with sql column names

Comment: thanks sir :D it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Dim da as As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM view_remit WHERE '" + volCbo + "' = '" & txtGroupBy.Text & "'",conn)
```

Comment: _...WHERE '" + volCbo + "'..._ a fieldname enclosed with a single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

`valCbo` is a field thus shall not be enclosed with a single quote(').

```
"Select * from view_remit WHERE " & valCbo  & " = '" & txtGroupBy.Text & "'"
```

Comment: found it! :D edited already. thanks for the "oh wait.." . LOL.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! but it gives this error though because when it loads, the  combo box is empty. i'll fix it. Thanks so much

Comment: thanks a bunch guys :D really big help.., all that trouble for that single quote.., (u.u)

Comment: You just need to add a validation if the cboShowOnly.Text is blank. :) That's a piece of cake to you I think so I won't specify it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
  If cboShowOnly.Text = "Province" Then
            valCbo = "Prov_Name"
    ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Municipality" Then
        valCbo = "Mun_Name"
    ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Bank" Then
        valCbo = "BANK_ACCNT"
    ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Branch" Then
        valCbo = "Branch_Name"
    ElseIf cboShowOnly.Text = "Assigned Account" Then
        valCbo = "Assigned_Account"
    End If

 declare @qry varchar(max)
 set @qry="Select * from view_remit WHERE " & valCbo  & " = '" &    txtGroupBy.Text & "'"
exec(@qry)
```